# Redis replication for read scaling with node

Tags: node.js, redis

I'd like to use Redis replication ("master-slave") as a means to achieve reading scalability. From I gathered from the documentation, I can have my reads split between many slaves - while I'm limited to write to the master.

I'm using node and there are two libraries out there that can be used to connect to redis: ioredis and node-redis. I was unable to understand how to setup any of those to do split reading so I don't know whether that's transparent (I guess not) or if none of those libs can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using [redis cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial), as it automatically takes care of sharding and distributing the load, giving you good future horizontal scalabality.

[ioredis does support](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#cluster) redis cluster, not sure about node-redis.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.